# Uniform Binary Search explanation and lookup table

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, search-algorithms, binary-search

Please can anyone explain me the worst ,average and best case running time for the Unifrom binary search .. Also how can the lookup table be explained?

Comment: We have [dozens of similar questions](http://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=binary+search+is%3Aquestion+-tree) and this is a standard result (i.e. found in literature). What have you tried, and where specifically did you get stuck?

Comment: This is not Binary Search  ... This is a UNIFROM BINARY SEARCH @Raphael

Comment: You are asking for "time complexity". That's the wrong notion here (problems have complexity, algorithms have costs such as runtime) but I understand it as "What is the Big-Oh?". And that won't change. Uniform binary search is a "bit jostling" optimisation that improves runtime in certain situations, but only in the constants. (You *can't* search faster than in $O(\log n)$ in an array, at least without preprocessing in $\Omega(n \log n)$. Do you know why?) Therefore, any analysis at the Landau level of granularity applies to both variants.

Comment: @Raphael why cant we search faster than O(logn) and please can you explain how is the lookup table used in the Uniform binary search for optimization?

Comment: These are two distinct questions; it'd be best if you posted each as a new question post here. Take care to [do some research](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=lower%20bound%20array%20search), think on the material, then elaborate on what you understand and formulate a question as pointed as possible. For instance, "Explain concept X?" is almost always a bad query.

Comment: @Raphael what i understand is that it does not divide the array in half as in binary searching rather a lookup table is used // But in how are the values in lookup table stored and what is the delta in an iteration